# Why didn't Doctor Strange summon the whole army in Infinity War?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, avengers-endgame

In *Infinity War*, why did Doctor Strange even let Thanos snap in the first place by letting half of them die and even giving away the Time Stone in the process only to later be reverse snapped back into existence?

Doesn't getting all of the heroes killed only to end up resurrecting them feel counter-intuitive?

Also, how did the resurrected superheroes even realise everyone needed to be there at such short notice?

Comment: It would be awesome if people could explain all these downvotes.

Comment: 1. This feels more like arguing why the story didn't go like you wished to have written it, which 2. makes it seem like a little all over the place because 3. it seems to be a mix of various questions, many of which have 4. been reiterated individually ad nauseam. On the bottom line, it seems to hang somewhere between "too broad" and "primarily opinion-based", with probably about 3 other existing duplicates.

Comment: Dr. Strange says he watched 14+ million possible futures, only one of which works.  So, obviously, he only does things which he knows play out in that one success.  Summoning an army was not in that one scenario.

Comment: But what if Doc strange hadn't wasted time in viewing all possible outcomes but instead had the idea of summoning whole army instead.

Answer (score 9):

**Thanos caught everyone off-guard** in *Infinity War*. The opening of the movie was a blitz that killed a bunch of Asgardians and wounded many more, followed almost immediately by an invasion on Earth. There wasn't enough time for Strange to coordinate with other sorcerers (he didn't open all those portals by himself) by the time he knew where Thanos was.

**Thanos was too powerful.** Thanos already had the Power and Space stones at his command by the time Dr. Strange became aware of the invasion. And by the time Strange knew where to go to fight him, he'd also collected the Reality and Soul stones (the latter of which was able to dispel all of Strange's enchantments in *Infinity War*).

**It wasn't that short.** The resurrection is the first in a sequence of many events. Thanos invades shortly afterward, but then, after remarking that arrogance is foolish, he decides to sit there and wait for Cap'n America to wake up so they can fight. The tres amigos battle and stall for several minutes as well -- plenty of time, presumably, for Strange to explain the situation to his fellow sorcerers, and for them to recruit forces to fight Thanos. It helps that most of the fallen would've reappeared in Wakanda or New Asgard, already grouped up and ready for battle.

In the final battle, Thanos is far weaker than his *Infinity War* incarnation. He is four years less experienced, doesn't have any Infinity Stone powers, and only has the forces he was able to gather at the time checkpoint Nebula brought him from, plus maybe any loyalists that happened to still be near Earth in 2023. His Death Star is taken out of play relatively quickly by Captain Marvel, who was "busy" during *Infinity War*. And he *still* comes extremely close to winning.

Strange presumably just had to wait for these exact circumstances to arise, otherwise nothing he did would've been enough.

A lot of these types of questions are probably going to get closed as "primarily opinion based" or something, but in case this one isn't, I gave it a shot.

Comment: 1. Doc Strange & team spent a whole lot of time waiting and planning at Titan waiting for Thanos. I don't think they were caught off-guard. They took the fight to him and didn't fight hard enough. 2. In my opinion Thanos was too overpowered here. Even without the Infinity stones he was easily beating everyone while with the Infinity gauntlet he almost lost twice.